# What is firstIndex in SwiftUI - Swift

Tags: swift, indexing, swiftui

While following the Apple tutorial about SwiftUI I found this:

```
1| var landmarkIndex: Int {
2|    userData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == landmark.id })!
3| }
```

Inside the tutorial line 2 isn't explained so well, they only say: 
"You’ll use landmarkIndex when accessing or updating the landmark’s favorite status, so that you’re always accessing the correct version of that data."

I can't understand what is firstIndex and what I am accessing by writing "$0.id == landmark.id"
Why am I creating this var?

Thank you so much - 
Nico

[Apple tutorial about SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input)

Comment: That's not specific to SwiftUI. `firstIndex` is from the various collection classes. This is a basic Swift question. The tutorial assumes you already know Swift.

Comment: You should read the [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) chapter of the Swift book (as well as the rest of the book) for a discussion of this syntax.

Comment: As mentioned, this is Swift, not SwiftUi. When using `firstIndex` you are searching through an ordered array to find the **first* occurrence of what you are searching for - in this case, `landmark.id`. The result is the zero-based index number of the hit. EDIT: you know, sometimes I hate spellcheck. It turned "occurrence" into "occupancy" without me knowing. :-)

Comment: Oh, I see. So it's searching for the index that is equal to landmark.id, right?

Comment: @rmaddy $0 is accessing the first parameter of the closure, but I can't understand what closure we are accessing

Comment: Did you read the Closures chapter I linked? Have you looked at the documentation for `firstIndex(where:)`? The closure is the block between the `{` and `}`.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2995097-firstindex).

Comment: Yep I read both but I didn't expect the closure to be that one itself, my bad and thank you!!!

Comment: Can't understand why this went -1: it can be helpful for other beginners that are doing the same tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to write this verbosely it would look something like this:

```
var landmarks: [LandMark] = []
for l in userData.landmarks {
  if isLandMarkEqual(l, landmark) {
    landmarks.append(l)
  }
}

func isLandMarkEqual(_ landmarkOne: LandMark, _ landmarkTwo: LandMark) -> Bool {
  return landmarkOne.id == landmarkTwo.id
}
```

We are iterating over userData.landmarks and calling a function (denoted by the {}) on every element. We then get the index of the first occurrence of an element that meets the condition laid out in the function (also called a closure).

If we were to simply return true e.g.

```
userData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { true })!
```

then the condition would be true for every element and therefore we would just get the first index in the collection aka 0.

$0 is simply shorthand for the first parameter in the function/closure. In our example this is equivalent to landmarkOne.

Comment: What does the `!` at the end of the line do?